# Ignore case sensitive for given word

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a search Query where I'm looking for values in my table. And I want to dynamically search for a value, for example, "AMAZON".

```
="select B, C, L, E, O, P, Q WHERE B >= date '"&TEXT(A2; "yyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(B2; "yyy-mm-dd")&"' and L matches '.*"&C2&".*' and E LIKE '%"&D2&"%'"
```

`"C2"` is my empty cell, for searching for a string. I, for example, input `"amazon"` into `"C2"`

**My problem** is that is doesn't return anything as in my table it's written "AMAZON" or probably "Amazon" so it won't find anything as I have a direct link to `"C2"`I couldn't figure out that way of phrasing the regular expression to ignore the case sensitive.
It would return anything as soon as I write `"AMAZON"` in `"C2"`.

**Goal:**

I want to make it non case sensitive. Cause at the moment my formula won't print anything as soon as I don't write it in initial letters.

Comment: Can't you use functions like `UPPER()` or `LOWER()`? Also, Excel might look like GS at first sight, though both are very different. Please pick the appropriate app.

Comment: You are not using regular expressions.

Comment: I'm using regular expressions in `"L machtes '.* MYTEXT *.'"`

Comment: And there is also where the questions starts, '.*(\w)[MYTEXT]*.'` I tried all kind of combinations for this...

Comment: UPPER() and LOWER() doesn't help me here as I don't know how it's written so I simply want to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `lower` in all cells you reference as well as all depending, returning columns.
So your formula would be:

```
="select B, C, L, E, O, P, Q WHERE B >= date '"&TEXT(A2; "yyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(B2; "yyy-mm-dd")&"' and lower(L) matches '.*"&lower(C2)&".*' and lower(E) LIKE '%"&lower(D2)&"%'"
```

Comment: Thank you @marikamitsos the solution lied not only in the regular expression of the matches. Instead, I also had to change the input table as well. This made it work.

Comment: Yes. It needs **all** cells, columns _"involved"_ to be wrapped by  `LOWER`. Glad I could help.